# discord.js Banning users outside server

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I was able to ban users outside the servers easily but I'm facing trouble in banning members outside or not in the server, here is my code:

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');

module.exports = {
    name: "ban",
    description: "Kicks a member from the server",

    async run (client, message, args) {

        if(!message.member.hasPermission("BAN_MEMBERS")) return message.channel.send('You can\'t use that!')
        if(!message.guild.me.hasPermission("BAN_MEMBERS")) return message.channel.send('I don\'t have the right permissions.')

        const member = message.mentions.members.first() || message.guild.members.cache.get(args[0]);

        if(!args[0]) return message.channel.send('Please specify a user');

        if(!member) return message.channel.send('Can\'t seem to find this user. Sorry \'bout that :/');
        if(!member.bannable) return message.channel.send('This user can\'t be banned. It is either because they are a mod/admin, or their highest role is higher than mine');

        if(member.id === message.author.id) return message.channel.send('Bruh, you can\'t ban yourself!');

        let reason = args.slice(1).join(" ");

        if(!reason) reason = 'Unspecified';

        member.ban(`${reason}`).catch(err => { 
          message.channel.send('Something went wrong')
            console.log(err)
        })

        const banembed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
        .setTitle('Member Banned')
        .setThumbnail(member.user.displayAvatarURL())
        .addField('User Banned', member)
        .addField('Kicked by', message.author)
        .addField('Reason', reason)
        .setFooter('Time kicked', client.user.displayAvatarURL())
        .setTimestamp()

        message.channel.send(banembed);


    }
}
```

I couldn't find out how to do son. Can you help me? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

The reason why your code will not work and run into errors is that the user is not a member, while you are trying to stick them into a GuildMember object, which is not possible.

The way to fix this is to use a user object instead.

`guild.members.ban()` is a method that accepts a user as a parameter.

Another thing to note is that getting msg.mentions.members.first() will create an error because you are not mentioning a member of your server. (again)

Therefore member needs to be changed to `message.mentions.users.first()` or `client.users.cache.get(args[0])`

And your ban code needs to be changed to:

```js
message.guild.members.ban(member).then(user => {
   message.channel.send(`Banned ${user.id}`);
}).catch(console.error);
```